# Why does my Java web project throw an error when I include EclipseLink-ModelGen(JPA 2.1) in my project library

Tags: java, jsp, jpa, servlets

> I'm experimenting on using JPA, [here is a screnshot of my project library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwrYm.png)
> I'm confused because if I don't include EclipseLink-ModelGen(JPA 2.1), my project compiles sucessfully and also runs properly but when I include it in either my project library or Processor-path libraries it throws the error below:

```
    warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source '12'
Note: Creating static metadata factory ...
1 warning


An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Generated
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.MetadataMirrorFactory.setEnvironments(MetadataMirrorFactory.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:368)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:985)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:901)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1227)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1339)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1258)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:936)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:311)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:57)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:57)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1404)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:1133)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.JavacTask.execute(JavacTask.java:120)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.forEach(Vector.java:1387)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:67)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:391)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:261)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:574)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:128)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Generated
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: What JDK version are you using to compile this? I'm guessing 9 or higher, because `javax.annotation.Generated` is not in the `java.base` module if I recall correctly

Comment: yes, I'm using JDK 12